# C# LinkedIn Rest API 401 Error

Tags: c#, oauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to access a user profile through their url as specified here https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api# in the format of a GET like this

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=<public-profile-url>
```

I know my oAuth is set up correctly because when I paste the completed oAuth url into a private browser I get valid XML back.  My problem is that when I try and access the url via code I get a 401 Unauthorized error.  I have tried accessing the valid url in all of the ways below and still get a 401. (*url* variable below is a valid oAuth url string)

```
webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Method = method.ToString();
webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
responseData = WebResponseGet(webRequest);

WebClient client = new WebClient();
responseData = client.DownloadString(url);

XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.Load(url);
responseData = doc1.ToString();
```

Why do I keep getting 401 errors?

Answer (score 0):

Traced the bug back to a .Net HttpWebRequest security limitation.  My solution is found here [C# HttpWebRequest GET partially encoded url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389003/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-get-partially-encoded-url/27389815#27389815)