# C# HttpWebRequest GET partially encoded url

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, webclient, linkedin-api

When I send a get using HttpWebRequest is seems to turn it into a uri, run it through an encoder and send the encoded string.  When I look at my address in the request after it is created I have the OriginalString which is correct and an AbsoluteUri which is encoded and incorrect.  My code and example urls are below.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
String responseData = WebResponseGet(webRequest);
```

OriginalString:"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Ffirstmlast"

AbsoluteUri:"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=https%3A//www.linkedin.com/in/firstmlast"

How can I force HttpWebRequest to send my original string that I passed it and not a uri?  Also I cannot send the already encoded string as a query string, LinkedIn requires it to be apart of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a HackedUri class here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xiangfan/archive/2012/01/16/10256915.aspx and created my request like this passing it a "Hacked Uri" instead of a string. This seems to be a security limitation problem with .Net.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(HackedUri.Create(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried double-encoding the relevant part of the URL?

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Ffirstmlast"));
```

Comment: Yes I did try that. Then it doesn't seem to encode it and I get the following AbsoluteUrl "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.linkedin.com%252Fin%252Ffirstmlast"  which is still doubly encoded.